# VS 2013 "Scanf" unsafe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to write a simple test program in VS 2013. It's telling me that `scanf()` is unsafe, and that I should use `scanf_s()` instead. Even worse, it's telling me that `int x` is uninitialized (and not just as a warning, as an error), even though it doesn't need to be initialized there. I'm wondering if it's possible to change settings so that VS2013 does not give me these error messages, or figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("How many pizzas did you make: ");
    int x;
    scanf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: use cout instead of printf() and cin instead of scanf

Comment: `scanf` isn't type-safe: you can tell it in the format string that you're passing an integer but give it the pointer to a floating-point number and that bug won't be caught until run-time, where you'll have a crash. Just use `std::cin` instead. The same goes for `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may be making mistake in the this line

```
  scanf("%d", &x);
```

Answer (score 3):

use cout instead of printf() and cin instead of scanf
example:

```
const int SIZE = 5; 
char word[SIZE]; 
cout << "Enter a word: ";
cin >> setw(SIZE) >> word;
cout << "You entered " << word << endl;
```

don't forget to import the std library

```
using std;
```

Comment: no, but printf and scanf are C funtions, cout and cin are for c++, since you're writing in VS they are more compatible, the functionality is almost the same, at the end they are not part of the language, just library

Comment: I heard printf/scanf uses less resources

Comment: the difference is tiny and actually is not a matter of the function, is the language, C++ does more work to compile. cin and cout are safer since you don't have to know the format, which makes scanf and printf easier to make a mistake

Comment: @Cornflower_blue: It differs from case to case. `operator<<` is an overloaded set of functions: if you don't print a float, its `operator<<` is not included in your program. The single `printf` supports all types and is therefore quite a bit bigger.

Answer (score 0):

scanf is warned as unsafe because it may cause buffer overflow. And scanf needs address of `x`, so it should be `&x`.

Comment: No possibility of buffer-overflow in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is one outright error and a probable bug in your example code:

```
scanf("%d", x);
```

The above needs a pointer, and you must always verify that all output parameters were matched.

To the second, Microsoft is behind the drive to force you to abandon the standard C library functions, going so far as to declaring their use an unsupportable risk, not that the *safer* functions in an optional part of the C standard cannot be used in an unsafe manner too.

Look in the compiler documentation, there is a flag to suppress this irritating behavior.

Anyway, you are writing in C++, so just about everyone here will say you should use iostreams and idiomatic C++, regardless of how you ask or why.

Comment: You should because using scanf and such in a C++ program is similar to: "I'm writing a Javascript program, why don't calls to Java functions work?" (and vice versa). They may have similar roots, but at this point in history, they are two totally different languages.

Comment: @casey: There are some advantages to using the standard C functions, though more for `printf` than for `scanf`: Using a format string instead of breaking up your string into chunks makes localisation easier for one. Anyway, I already included that idiomatic C++ is preferred. The comparison of javascript and java is several orders of magnitude too steep, those are C++ functions, even if just bare-metal ones. Anyway, going low-level is not an error in the right circumstances, and I'm a bit disappointed by the huge crowd that mindlessly condemns everything not using at least 50 templates per line

Comment: When you put it that way, it makes sense. (I am disappointed by the overuse of templates and lambdas as well, I avoid templates unless I absolutely have to use them besides, VC2010/2012 doesn't fully support the standard anyhow so I've never tried lambdas or move semantics...they scare me more than anything else).